# Grepping correct value in 'else'

Tags: bash, shell, osx-mountain-lion

The following is a snippet from a daily report script that checks on the SMART status of disks.

I'd like the full value of $STATUS to be printed in the 'else' clause, however, but it's truncating it now to only the first word ($3).

How can I overcome this?

```
echo "SMART STATUS" >> $LOGS
echo "--------------------------" >> $LOGS
DISKS=( 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 )

for i in "${DISKS[@]}" ;

do

STATUS=`diskutil info /dev/disk$i | grep SMART | awk '{ print $3 }'`

if [ "$STATUS" = "Verified" ]; then
        echo "SMART STATUS OK FOR DISK $i" >> $LOGS
else

        echo "** SMART STATUS $STATUS FOR DISK $i **" >> $LOGS
fi
done

echo " " >> $LOGS
echo " " >> $LOGS
```

For example:

```
$ diskutil info /dev/disk8 | grep SMART                     
   SMART Status:             Not Supported
$ diskutil info /dev/disk2 | grep SMART 
   SMART Status:             Verified
```

Ideally the script would echo "Not Supported" for cases like disk8. I think the value for "SMART Status:" may vary between one word and several. I don't see all the possibilities on the man page, so I don't have a definitive answer for this.

Comment: Instead of doing ``echo blah blah >> $LOGS`` consider wrapping all the code in ``{...ALL-YOUR-CODE...} >> $LOGS 2>&1`` then you can remove all those ``>> $LOGS`` then everything going to stdout and stderr will be captured in your log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save the `grep`, and put all things in awk:

try this:

```
STATUS=$(diskutil info /dev/disk$i|awk -F': *' '/SMART/{print $2}')
```

Comment: yours is the most perfect answer! Works brilliantly. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Is this fits your needs ?

```
disks="0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7"

for i in $disks; do
    status=$(diskutil info /dev/disk$i | awk '/SMART/{$1=$2="";print}')

    if [[ $status == *Verified* ]]; then
            echo "SMART status OK for disk $i"
    else
            echo "** SMART status $status for disk $i **"
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

## `cut` solution

If you can rely on the number of spaces printed by `diskutil`, you can just begin cutting at the first char of the status:

```
STATUS=`diskutil info /dev/disk$i | grep SMART | cut -c 30-`
```

## `awk` solution

The word `Supported` is caught as `$4`, so we can use an if statement to check, whether the word is filled:

```
STATUS=`diskutil info /dev/disk$i | grep SMART | awk '{ if($4 != "") print $3,$4; else print $3; }'`
```

Comment: `awk` is capable of greping itself, no need to pipe, see my response.

Answer (score 0):

If you have GNU grep, you can do:

```
STATUS=$(diskutil info /dev/disk$i | grep -oP '(?<=SMART Status:).*')
```

The contents of the variable will contain leading whitespace. However, your if condition can accomodate that:

```
shopt -s extglob
if [[ ${STATUS##*([[:space:]])} == Verified ]]; then
```

Comment: You could match the spaces in the Perl-style regex, and maybe make the trailing `.*` a little less greedy by using `\w.*` to match a word-character followed by anything, couldn't you?

Comment: look-behind assertions must be fixed width. You can't put `\s*` in there.

Comment: Oh...bother...you're probably right (about variable length look-behind).  I hardly ever use them, so I forget that.